# Redis | Best data structure to store IPs and networks

Tags: redis

My goal is to store in Redis:

- Plain IP addresses like  `228.228.228.228`
- IP networks like `228.228.228.0/24`

in order to check in request/response cycle whether or not
current IP `xxx.yyy.xxx.vvv` is inside( contained by):

- Plain ips

or

- Ip network ( for example `228.228.228.228` inside `228.228.228.0/24`)

Overall amount of ips and networks  - few 1000 items.

Question is – what is the best way (best structure) to store both plain ips and networks in Redis and make aforementioned check without fetching data from Redis?

Thanks.

P.S. Current IP is already known.

**UPDATE**

Ok, lets simplify it a bit with example.

I have 2 ips and 2 networks in where I want to check if certain ip is contained.

```
# 2 plain ip
202.76.250.29
37.252.145.1

# 2 networks
16.223.132.0/24
9.76.202.0/24
```

There are 2 possible ways where exact ip might be contained:

1)Just in plain ips. For example `202.76.250.29` contained in the structure above and `215.08.11.23` is not contained simply by definition.

2)Ip might be contained inside network. For example `9.76.202.100` contained inside networks `9.76.202.0/24` but not contained inside list of plain ips as there are no any exact ip = `9.76.202.100.`

Little bit of of explanation about ip networks. Very simplified.

Ip network represents range of ips. For example ipv4 network `"192.4.2.0/24"` represents 256 ip addresses:

```
IPv4Address('192.4.2.1'), IPv4Address('192.4.2.2'),
…
…
…
IPv4Address('192.4.2.253'), IPv4Address('192.4.2.254')
```

In another words ip network is a range of ip addresses

```
from '192.4.2.1' up to '192.4.2.254'
```

In our example `9.76.202.100` contained inside networks `9.76.202.0/24`  as one of this addresses inside the range.

My idea is like this:

Any ip address can be represented as integer. One of our ip addresses
`202.76.250.29` converted to integer is `3394042397`.

As ip network is a range of ips, so that it is possible to convert it in a range of integers by converting first and last ip in range in integers.
For example one of our networks  `16.223.132.0/24` represents range between `IPv4Address('16.223.132.1')` and `IPv4Address('16.223.132.254')`. Or integers range from `283083777` up to  `283083781` with step `1`.

Individual ip can be represented as range between it’s integer and it’s integer + 1 (lower bound included, upper bound excluded).

Obviously search in plain ips can be done by putting them to `SET` and then using `SISMEMBER`. But what about searching inside networks. Can we do some trick with ranges maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Best" is subjective(in memory, in speed etc) but you may use two sets/hash to store them. Since they are unique both `hashes` and `sets` would be fine. If you prefer you can use a single set/hash to save both ip and network ip addresses but i would prefer separate since they are two different type of data sets(just like database tables).

Then you can use either of those

- `SISMEMBER` with O(1) time complexity
- `HEXISTS` with O(1) time complexity.

It can be handled on application level with multiple commands or lua script(in a single transaction).

Depending on your choice add to your keys with `SADD` and `HSET`(the field value would be 1).

--
Edit: (hope i get it right)

For the range of network addresses create sets from the integers surrounding two dots such as 12.345.67.1-12.345.67.254 range will be represented as `12.345.67` and you will add this to the set. When you want to search for `12.345.67.x` it will be parsed into `12.345.67` in your application level and you will check with `SISMEMBER`. Same can be done with hash with `HEXISTS`.

Since ip addresses contain four different numbers with three dots, you will discard last dot and last number and the rest will be representing(i assume) the network range.

Comment: @ Thanks for the answer but it does not solve the problem how to chek if 127.0.0.1 is inside  network 127.0.0.0/24.SISMEMBER  as far as i undestand just use HASH to find out whether or not something inside set of stored values. Real trouble here is how to represent ip network in Redis to be able to chek if ip inside network or not

Comment: fro example Postgres uses *inet '192.168.1.5' << inet '192.168.1/24'* containment operator to check it. Need something similiar in Redis

Comment: @AlekseiKhatkevich thanks for the message, i am not familiar with the domain - if it is like 192.168.1.5 then first three numbers(192,168,1) will form a group and any number comes that includes those three (192.168.1.x/y) will be considered it is in that network ? Can you update the question with some example use cases and their expected result.

Comment: I have updated question with explanation. Please check if you have a time..

Comment: @AlekseiKhatkevich i added a "possible" solution for network ip range. Please comment again if i didn't get it right.

Answer (score 1):

For IPs you can use Set and query by certain IP within O(1) time.

For IP range, I think you can use List with Lua Script for query. List will have O(n) time for searching, but since you only have 1000 items, O(N) and O(1) will not have a huge difference for Redis in memory query.